# Appcelerator Can't select provisioning profile

Tags: ios, appcelerator, adhoc

I just updated to the latest version of appcelerator, and when I attempt to package for iOS Adhoc/Enterprise I am unable to select a provisioning profile (I can't actually select any provisioning profiles). 
I have an Enterprise account and when I click the manage settings links I am able to see the provisioning profile there.

The application ID's line up and everything else seems in order. Has anyone run into this problem or found a work around for it?

Comment: Yes, I just ran into this problem today.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this if anyone else is stuck here. I ended up going around Appcelerator Studio all together and deployed it through the CLI. I understand this isn't really an answer, but if you need something to get done you can use this syntax:

appc run -p ios -T dist-adhoc -R "distribution cert name" -P "provisioning profile uuid" -O "/location"

Full description: 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks-section-src-43306725_AppceleratorCLITasks-iOSAdHocDistribution